# 'To' address being added twice while using PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer to send mails. However, the mail is being sent to each user twice. Below is the screen-shot of a test mail.
[image]

The following is my code :

```
<?php

##REQUIRED FUNCTION
function send_mail_to($receiver, $msg)
{
    $subject="[ TNP Update ] - Do you like the new look ?";
    #Grab the PHPmailer class
    require_once('./lib/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php');

    #Create object
    $mailer = new PHPmailer(); //Instantiate class
    $mailer->From="tnp@aakashbhowmick.in";
    $mailer->FromName="TNP Mailer";
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);
    $mailer->Subject = $subject;
    $mailer->Body = $msg;
    $mailer->AddAddress($receiver);
    #Send the email
    set_time_limit(300);
    $mailer->Send();

} //End of send_mail_to()

    ###### THE WORKING CODE ######

#Only authorised access is allowed.
if($_POST['signature']=="some-secret-signature-here"){
    $msg1=urldecode($_POST['text']);

    # Formatting the message a little
    $msg1=str_replace("#c0c0c0","#EAE99A",$msg1);
    $msg1=str_replace("<td","<td style='font-family:Trebuchet MS,Verdana,arial'; ",$msg1);

    #Start sending mails. Some lines commented for testing purpose
    //include("connection.php");
    //$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers");
    $subscriber=array('id'=>'1','email'=>'aakashrocks@gmail.com','active'=>'1');
    //while($subscriber=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($subscriber['active']==1){  

            $body="Some text";
                send_mail_to($subscriber['email'], $body); 

        }    #End-of-if
    //}   #End-of-while

} ##End of if
?>
```

Comment: Maybe a look at the mailheaders give you a clue.

Comment: In gmail, click the little down arrow by "me, me" - make sure one of them isn't a CC or BCC?

Comment: anybody find the solution? please post it?

Comment: Did anyone find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, for me solution was to change

```
$mailer->isSMTP();
```

to

```
$mailer->Mailer   = 'smtp';
```

---

So, try to use `$mailer->Mailer`.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a page refresh and hence multiple execution - Make sure the mail method is called only once by the browser for each reciever. To make sure, you could set a session variable upon sending and go into the send part only if session is not set.

```
  if(!isset($_SESSION[$reciever]))
    {
       $_SESSION[$reciever] = 1;
       \\mail code here
    }
  else{
        echo "doing it more than once";
     }
```

Also you can set  $mailer->$SingleTo to true, so you would know if its multiple execution or single. You could also send the timestamp with the email for more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but using the SMTP connection. 
I still don't know why but it happens when your recipient doesn't have a name.
So, instead of

```
$mailer->AddAddress($receiver);
```

Do

```
$mailer->AddAddress($receiver, 'Receiver name');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the solution.  I have the same problem using `$receipt->AddCC($params['email'], "$first_name $last_name");`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem.  In my case changing mail systems did the trick.

By default, phpMailer sends out email using Mail.  Once I told it to use Sendmail instead, I stopped getting the duplicate address.

```
$email = new phpmailer;
$email->mailer = "sendmail";
```