# phpMailer: Send emails to multiple recipients

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails to multiple recipients.

So far, I was able to retrieve the email addresses in an array. But the mail function somehow does not accept the email addresses. Instead, it gives an error that it needs at least one email address to send an email, and it displays the emails inside the array.

Have a look at my code below.

```
$email = "select email from student"; 


if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{
$address = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
{     
$address[] = $row;
}  

for ($i = 0; $i < count($address); $i++) {
$all_address[] = implode(';', $address[$i]);
}

foreach ($all_address as $aa) {

$mail->AddAddress($aa);
}
```

Hope that you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what all that other code is for but something like this should be fine:

```
if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{ 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
  {     
    $mail->AddAddress($row[0]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it gives an error: Notice: Undefined index: email in ... $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);

Comment: I tried by sending 2 emails, and it works. But when I checked on the emails, both of the 2 addresses received 2 emails.

Comment: 2 rows, as I have queried 2 addresses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192682/to-address-being-added-twice-while-using-phpmailer

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have one redundant array - not sure why you need to implode addresses ...

```
$email = "select email from student"; 


if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{
$address = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
{     
$address[] = $row;
}  

foreach ($address as $aa) {

$mail->AddAddress($aa);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried you code but it gives me this error: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ....\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php

Comment: @user2352236 try to check what is in the address[] please